# Shoukd I use JSON for my posting and commenting system?

Tags: php, json

I am building a social networking website and should i use JSON instead of database for storing users posts and comments? Is it good and secure?

Comment: Not for storing, no. Where yould you store that json anyway if not in a database? In Files? // For transmitting data: Yes.

Comment: a database is going to be far better solution

Comment: Thank you for your reply but where should I actually use JSON in my social networking website? Please give me a real world example!

Comment: This question and comments are showing very little research done.

Comment: I have done research but couldn't get straight answer! Please tell me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSON is a format, not a file standard. So you could even think of storing JSON in DB.

So, you will need to answer two questions

- is file format better than real DB format (like MySQL like databases)?
- is JSON format good for the use I have?

**File format**

Because you will have to deal with quick access and sometimes complex queries (search engine, statistics, ... ), it's clear that a DB system will be much more efficient than a file system oriented solution. File creations / openings / writings / closings need a lot of time and it will be a pain to create search queries. In PHP you would have to open all your files and put them in memory beforte doing the real job.

Using a Database, you would perhaps be directly be able to ask the system if someone with "%john%" in his name has posted something about "%futurama%" in the title.

*So... one point for DB*

**JSON format stored in DB**

One more time, you'd better use rows capacities of the DB system. By that, I mean using a author_id row for example. It would greatly impact the perfs. On the other hand, you would have to think of complex queries dealing with the downsides of the JSON format in your DB engine query.

*One more point for not using JSON*

**But when using JSON?**

JSON is great when dealing with APIs. If you need to serve data for an application (i.e. an Angular2 front end that will query your API), JSON is a native format to manage data... but not for storing it... JSON is more often used for stream purposes.